# Adding background img to HTML site using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am currently building a website from scratch and am having an issue with adding a background image. I currently have everything saved on a flash drive and am working through there so I can travel and work on this on other computers.

Here is what the main folders look like:
[image: main path]

I have the CSS file saved in assets/CSS/welcome/
I have the image I want to add located at images/welcome/

This is the CSS code I have and I have tried a lot of different things.

`/* Background image */ background-image: url(images/welcome/6.jpg);`

I was able to get the CSS to work if I wrote the CSS in the HTML coding. I am wanting to differentiate the 2 so I can work on them and not have such large lines of code.

I've tried to change the where the image folder was so it would be easier to access, attempted different paths including "../images/welcome/6.jpg" and "/images/welcome/6.jpg"

I don't really know how to get from the CSS to the images folders to access these. Thank you in advance!

Comment: a file-relative path has to be relative to the CSS file. So it should be `../../images/welcome/6.jpg` to leave both the welcome and the CSS folder. Or you can go root-relative with `./imageswelcome/6.jpg`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried to use the "../../images/welcome/6.jpg" and it did not seem to work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: a complete file structure would be helpful here. Did you also cleared or disabled the cache? Images are one of the first thing to be cached

Comment: thats true I missed the full path. isherwood is correct here.

Comment: @isherwood  lol, I just now attempted to do "../../../../images/6.jpg" and it still did not show up. I did clear my cache as well.  Dont know if I can really do a proper file structer but Ill try.

This is all in the main folder
assets - CSS - welcome - styles.css
images - welcome - 6.jpg
index.html

Comment: wow that came out terribly...